# Web hosts for controversial (yet legal) content

Tags: web-hosting, recommendations

A lot of web hosts will take down a site at the first hint of trouble. What sites can I use to host controversial (yet legal) content?

(Examples of such content might be a whistleblower site or an opinionated blog. Examples of things which this question would not cover would be jihad sites, child molester sites, piratebay-style bittorrent sites, etc.)

Comment: When you say legal, what jurisdictions are you thinking of? "Legal" means different things, in say, New York vs Tokyo vs Dubai vs Melbourne, etc.

Comment: The "legal" isn't the gist of the question, it's there to qualify the question so that it doesn't look like "where can I host my terrorist jihad child molester site" or something. This is like "where can I host a whistleblower site?". "What is it legal to host in Dubai?" is a different question.

Comment: Yeah, I think I understand what you mean. But "controversial" varies from place to place. One jurisdiction's "outrageous" is another jurisdiction's "boring."

Comment: OK, that is true but I think it's fairly clear what I mean here: hosts which have a robust attitude to content-based complaints.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an article from 2007: [**Free Speech Hosting: 11 Web Hosts That Won't Dump You at the First Sign of Controversy**](http://whdb.com/2007/free-speech-hosting-11-web-hosts-that-wont-dump-you-at-the-first-sign-of-controversy/).

All but one of the hosts mentioned are still in business, though not all of them clearly emphasize how they treat controversial material:

- <strike>[1st-Amendment.Net](http://www.1st-amendment.org/index.php)</strike> (Closed)
- [Computer Tyme](http://www.ctyme.com/) (Emphasizes free speech hosting)
- [Free Speech Web Hosting](http://freespeechwebhosting.com/) (Emphasizes free speech hosting)
- [Project DoD](http://hosting.dod.net/) (Emphasizes free speech hosting)
- [Zensurfrei](http://www.zensurfrei.com/howorder.htm) (Emphasizes free speech hosting)
- [Grex](http://www.grex.org/) (Emphasizes free speech hosting)
- [CrisisHost](http://www.crisishost.com/) (Emphasizes free speech hosting)
- [NearlyFreeSpeech.Net](https://www.nearlyfreespeech.net/) (Emphasizes free speech hosting)
- [SecureServerTech](http://www.secureservertech.com/hosting/)
- [iWeb8](http://iweb8.com/)
- [Beachcomber](http://beachcomber.net/hosting.htm)

Comment: Looks like some of those have gone out of business as hosts.

Answer (score 4):

I've just started an account with [NearlyFreeSpeech.net](https://www.nearlyfreespeech.net/) (not actually doing anything with it yet though) and this is pretty much one of their raisons d'etre. From their [abuse page](https://www.nearlyfreespeech.net/help/abuse):

> When our members upload content to our service, they are asserting two things:
>
> - That the content is legal in the United States.
> - That they have the legal right to make the content available

and

> Please do not assume that we support
>   or endorse all the content posted by
>   our members. We believe that freedom
>   of speech is the inalienable right of
>   all people. Consequently, we do not
>   censor our members on the basis of
>   content, no matter how offensive or
>   repugnant we may personally find that
>   content to be. Our company would have
>   to have a different name if we only
>   allowed members to publish
>   uncontroversial content that we happen
>   to agree with.

Which pretty much covers both parts of your question.

Depending on what you want to do they may not be suitable (no SSL at the moment, can't run persistent processes, seems to be aimed at a fairly technical client base), but the price seems good, and the only support request I've had so far (software upgrade) happened reasonably quickly and without problems.

As I say though, I've only just signed up (and that was based on price rather than planning to host controversial content), so I haven't really given them a chance to disappoint me yet.

Comment: In fact one can run persistent processes in the pools beta.